# Exposing Kafka cluster in Kubernetes using LoadBalancer service

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

Suppose if I have 3 node Kafka cluster setup. Then how do I expose it outside a cloud using Load Balancer service? I have read reference material but have a few doubts.

Say for example below is a service for a broker

```
apiVersion: v1 
  kind: Service metadata: 
  name: kafka-0 
  annotations: dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-0.kafka.my.company.com 
  spec: 
    externalTrafficPolicy: Local 
    type: LoadBalancer 
    ports: 
      - port: 9092 
      name: outside 
      targetPort: 9092 
    selector: app: kafka kafka-pod-id: "0"
```

1. What is port and targetPort?
2. Do I setup LoadBalancer service for each of the brokers?
3. Do these multiple brokers get mapped to single public IP address of cloud LB?
4. How does a service outside k8s/cloud access individual broker? By using `public-ip:port`? or by using `kafka-<pod-id>.kafka.my.company.com:port`?. Also which port is used here? `port` or `targetPort`?
5. How do I specify this configuration in Kafka broker's `Advertised.listeners` property? As port can be different for services inside k8s cluster and outside it.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the information you provided I will try give you some answers, eventually give some advise.

**1)** `port:` is the port number which makes a service visible to other services running within the same K8s cluster.  In other words, in case a service wants to invoke another service running within the same Kubernetes cluster, it will be able to do so using port specified against `port` in the service spec file.

`targetPort:` is the port on the `POD` where the service is running. Your application needs to be listening for network requests on this port for the service to work.

**2/3)**  Each Broker should be exposed as `LoadBalancer` and be configured as headless service for internal communication. There should be one addiational `LoadBalancer` with external ip for external connection.

Example of Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka-0
  annotations: dns.alpha.kubernetes.io/external: kafka-0.kafka.my.company.com
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 9092
    name: kafka-port
    protocol: TCP
  selector:
    pod-name: kafka-0
  type: LoadBalancer
```

**4)** You have to use `kafka-<pod-id>.kafka.my.company.com:port`

**5)** It should be set to the external addres so that clients can connect to it. [This](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) article might help with understanding.

Similar case was on Github, it might help you also - https://github.com/kow3ns/kubernetes-kafka/issues/3

In addition, You could also think about Ingress - https://tothepoint.group/blog/accessing-kafka-on-google-kubernetes-engine-from-the-outside-world/